# Solving system of two linear odes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve 
\begin{align}
y_1'+B_{12}y_1=\beta_{12}y_2\\
Ay_2'+B_{21}y_2=\beta_{21}y_1,
\end{align}with $y_1(0)=y_2(0)=y_0$.
I find the eigenvalues to be $$\lambda_{1,2}=-\frac{B_{12}}{2}-\frac{B_{21}}{2A}-\frac{\sqrt{(AB_{12}-B_{21})^2+4A\beta_{12}\beta_{21}}}{2A}$$
For $\lambda_1$, I get eigenvector $(\beta_{12},B_{12}+\lambda_1)^T$ and for  $\lambda_2$, I get $(\beta_{12},B_{12}+\lambda_2)^T$. After simplification, i obtain
$$y_1(t)=y_0\frac{(\beta_{12}-\lambda_2-B_{12})e^{\lambda_1t}-(\beta_{12}-\lambda_1-B_{12})e^{\lambda_2t}}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}.$$ I cannot get $y_2(t)$ which must be $$y_2(t)=y_0\frac{(\beta_{21}-A\lambda_2-B_{21})e^{\lambda_1t}-(\beta_{21}-A\lambda_1-B_{21})e^{\lambda_2t}}{A(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can consider the equations to be written as

$$
\left[
\begin{eqnarray}
y'_1 + B_{12} y_1 &=& \beta_{12} y_2\\
y'_2 + B_{21} y_2 &=& \beta_{21} y_1\\
\end{eqnarray}
\right.
$$

---

Now we consider

$$
y_\pm = y_1 + \alpha_\pm y_2,
$$

whence

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
y_\pm' = y_1' + \alpha_\pm y_2' &=&
  - B_{12} y_1 + \beta_{12} y_2 - \alpha_\pm B_{21} y_2 + \alpha_\pm \beta_{21} y_1\\
&=& \Big( \alpha_\pm \beta_{21} - B_{12} \Big) y_1
  + \Big( \beta_{12} - \alpha_\pm B_{21} \Big) y_2\\
&=& \Big( \alpha_\pm \beta_{21} - B_{12} \Big) \left[
  y_1 + \underbrace{ \frac{ \beta_{12} - \alpha_\pm B_{21} }
    { \alpha_\pm \beta_{21} - B_{12} } }_{\displaystyle \alpha_\pm} y_2
\right]\\
&=& \Big( \alpha \beta_{21} - B_{12} \Big) y.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So the general solution is given by

$$
y_\pm = y_0 \exp\Big[ (\alpha_\pm \beta_{21} - B_{12}) t \Big],
$$

and

$$
\left[
\begin{eqnarray}
y_1 &=& \frac{\alpha_+ y_-}{\alpha_+ - \alpha_-}
  - \frac{\alpha_- y_+}{\alpha_+ - \alpha_-}\\
y_2 &=& \frac{y_+}{\alpha_+ - \alpha_-}
  - \frac{y_-}{\alpha_+ - \alpha_-}
\end{eqnarray}
\right.
$$

We need to find $\alpha_\pm$, which is given by

$$
\alpha_\pm = \frac{ \beta_{12} - \alpha_\pm B_{21} }{ \alpha_\pm \beta_{21} - B_{12} },
$$

so

$$
\alpha_\pm = \frac{B_{12} - B_{21}}{2 \beta_{21}} \pm \frac{1}{2 \beta_{21}}
\sqrt{ \Big( B_{12} - B_{21} \Big)^2 + 4 \beta_{12} \beta_{21} }.
$$

The general solution can now be written as

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
y_-(t) &=& y_0 \exp \Bigg[ \tfrac{1}{2} \Big( - B_{12} - B_{21} -
   \sqrt{ \Big( B_{12} - B_{21} \Big)^2 + 4 \beta_{12} \beta_{21} } \Big) t \Bigg]\\
y_+(t) &=& y_0 \exp \Bigg[ \tfrac{1}{2} \Big( - B_{12} - B_{21} +
   \sqrt{ \Big( B_{12} - B_{21} \Big)^2 + 4 \beta_{12} \beta_{21} } \Big) t \Bigg]\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

and

$$
\left[
\begin{eqnarray}
y_1 &=& \frac{\alpha_+ y_-}{\alpha_+ - \alpha_-}
  - \frac{\alpha_- y_+}{\alpha_+ - \alpha_-}\\
y_2 &=& \frac{y_+}{\alpha_+ - \alpha_-}
  - \frac{y_-}{\alpha_+ - \alpha_-}
\end{eqnarray}
\right.
$$

Comment: why is $y_\pm(0)=y_0$? Remember $y_1(0)=y_2(0)=y_0$

Comment: @Vaolter: That is a good remark, it should be $y_\pm(0) = (1 + \alpha_\pm) y_0$ - but it does however not change the method...

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get this solution to be in terms of $\lambda_{1,2}$ which is slightly different from $\alpha_{\pm}$. Can you help with that?